# Can I provide a joining argument for the first argument of an objective c function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

```objectivec
- (void)testThisFunction:joiningArgument1(id)argument1 {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Hello: ");
}
```

[This tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_functions.htm) talks about how there are "joining arguments" which are exposed at the call site.  However, when I try to create a joining argument for the first argument, then I get `Expected method body` error likely because it breaks the syntax.

Can I give the first argument a "joining argument" or is that not allowed? If it is allowed, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

In objective c you can't define a label for first Argument or parameter the convention for this is like:

```
- (void)testThisFunctionWithJoiningArgument1:(id)argument1 {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Hello: ");
}

- (void)methodNameWithFirstParam:(id)firstParam secondPraram:(id)secondParam {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Hello: ");
}
```